# I am trying to indent a HTML form and it does not see them

Tags: html

I am trying to create a Custom registration form template, and when I try to put in paragraph spaces (returns) or indents the program refuses to see them, even in the preview pane.  Please help.

I am trying to place this form on top of a bckground image placed at the center. the image is inside a coloumn of a table. I want to indent the form so that it\s completely inside the image, n all to its left.

Comment: What do you expect from us exactly, when you don't even give us anything to debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to use `padding` for such purposes, not any characters, if I understand your intentions correctly. Try adding this css property for the form:

```
padding-left: Xpx;
```

With X being your desired number of pixels for indentation.